# Set apex:variable from javascript

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, variable

I have a question: I need to set the value of an apex:variable (test) equal to a javascript variable (result). You can see my code below:

```
    window.onload = function(){

        console.log(document.getElementById("productId").textContent);
        var prodID = document.getElementById("productId").textContent;
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction('{!$RemoteAction.ProductDetailController.retrieveAskForQuoting}', prodID, function(result, event){

            // Success case!
            if(event.status){

                document.getElementById("visibility").value = result;
            }               
        });
    }

</script>
```

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Please explain why you feel this implementation strategy is necessary.

Comment: I need to pass a value from visualforce to the controller because I need to set a non-static variable and, as per the definition, a remote action needs to be declared as static. Thus, I cannot reference a non-static variable from a static context.